# How do I use jQuery to generate a paragraph with ID 'blurb' in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div element on my web page with ID "map" with a link to Google inside of it.

```
<div id="map">
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to generate a paragraph after the link with an ID of "blurb," so the HTML akin to what the Javascript produces is

```
<div id="map">
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
    <p id="blurb"></p>
</div>
```

I have been experimenting with

```
$('#map').append('p').attr('id', 'blurb');
```

to no avail.

I am open to a Javascript, but non-jQuery way to do this as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#map').append('<p id="blurb"></p>');
```

Your method was the right general idea, but was just appending the text 'p' rather than the tag `<p>` and the id wasn't getting set on the right object because of the way jQuery chaining works for `.append()`.

If you wanted to assign the id programmatically for some reason, then it's probably easier to do that this way:

```
$('<p>').attr('id', 'blurb').appendTo('#map');
```

Comment: @DavidFaux - Take the # out of the id in your HTML so it's `id="map"`, not `id='#map'`.  After fixing that, it works here:   It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/QzKLp/10/..  I'd also suggest you finish the content before appending rather than after appending as that will require less reflow operations in the browser.

Answer (score 4):

First, set up all attributes, then append.

```
$('<p>').attr('id', 'blurb').appendTo('#map');
```

Comment: in the given example `<p>` does not exist yet, so you can't select it `I want to use jQuery to generate a paragraph after the link with an ID of "blurb,"`

Comment: sorry, i thought used `append` , `appendTo` creates elements on the fly as stated here http://api.jquery.com/append/. Thanks for clarifying it though cheers

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working for some reason. jsfiddle.net/QzKLp/2

Comment: tried using it in google chrome's console `TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of null`

Comment: @DavidFaux: you have `<div id="#map">`. Nothing will work here. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work for two reasons. First of all append can take text and you must distinguish between text and HTML by using a tag (`<p>`) instead of `p`. The other reason is that chaining means jQuery's append function will return the jQuery object that it is called on. In this case an object refering to your map element. So when you set the id you were setting the id of the map div, not of your newly create element (assuming the `<p>` error was fixed). Also you should use prop to set the id instead of attr, but both will probably work for id. Here is some example code:

jQuery:

```
$('<p>').appendTo('#map').prop('id', 'blurb');
```

Plain Javascript (Faster, but less legible):

```
var pel = document.createElement('p');
pel.id = 'blurb';
document.getElementById('map').appendChild(pel);
```